# Не работает отладка в VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Перешел с Visual Studio на VS Code.
Скачал, все настроил. Написал простую программу, нажал F5 и выдало ошибку:

launch: program 'c:\Users...\Рабочий стол\nothing\build\Debug\outDebug' does not exist

и предлагает открыть 'launch.json'

Пытался найти решение в инете, но там у людей проблемы намного сложнее. У меня вроде все просто, но в настройках этого файла не разбираюсь . Помогите пожалуйста

Код файла 'launch.json' :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/danya/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/nothing",
      "program": "c:/Users/danya/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/nothing/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

В файле c_cpp_properties.json ошибка в строке "compilerPath": "gcc",
Код файла 'launch.json' :

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Видимо у вас не установлен компилятор gcc или его нету в path

Comment: скорее всего второе, я помню, что при установке убирал галку как то связанную с PATH. Не подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: https://russianblogs.com/article/51811722546/